# Java Calculator Variable

Tags: java, variables, methods, declaration

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class javaCalculator {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    setNumbers(x,y);//---->>>>Problem
    addNumbers(x,y);//---->>>Problem
    multiplyNumbers(x,y);//---->>>Problem

}



public static double[] setNumbers(double x, double y) {

    Scanner set = new Scanner(System.in);

    double[] inputs = new double[2];
    System.out.println("Enter First Number");

    x = inputs [0] = set.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
    y =  inputs [1] = set.nextDouble();
    return inputs;

}


 public static double addNumbers(double x, double y){

   double addition = x+y;
   System.out.println(addition);
    return addition;
 }

public static double multiplyNumbers(double x, double y){

    double multiply = x+y;
    System.out.println(multiply);
    return multiply;
}

}
```

The problem is that it says x and y are not initialised.

I don't know how to do that,  i declared them in the setNumbers and want to use those for addition and multiplication.

If i declare them again in main then x and y will have values 0 and that wont help me.

THANK YOU.

Also i am new to java. Can someone explain why my software intelliJ also says to use

```
   static//--->>in all the name of the methods
```

in English please, i wont understand if you make it sound complicated.

once again thank you.

Comment: what you mean? i know how to code i have done c but i have always had trouble with linking methods and stuff

Comment: you've just said _The problem is that it says x and y are not initialised.I don't know how to do that_. the solution to that is doing some tutorials/study.

Comment: Studying your texts and notes will fix that problem. This is Java at its most basic, and the only solution is study.

Comment: can you tell me any good places to study this stuff?

Comment: there are a lot of stuff online that just go through if and else and other type of stuff that i dont really need to go through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program **starts execution** in the `main` method. The first statement that Java executes is

```
setNumbers(x,y);
```

at that point you didn't define any `x` or `y` variable. Thus the error.

Note that `method(x, y)` means that you want to call a method and give it additional information, two variables, on the way. So you need to provide such variables like

```
double x = 1;
double y = 2;
setNumbers(x, y);
```

then the method will be called with those parameters. However, your `setNumbers` method doesn't seem to use the variables in any way, you just try to overwrite them:

```
x = inputs [0] = set.nextDouble();
y =  inputs [1] = set.nextDouble();
```

Which would have no effect on the program since `x` and `y` inside the method are not connected anymore to the scope outside of the world, Java is [pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

If you want the method to assign two variables and then use them later you should call it without arguments and then return the values:

```
// In main method
double[] numbers = setNumbers();
double x = numbers[0];
double y = numbers[1];

// setNumbers method
public static double[] setNumbers() {
    double[] input = new double[2];
    input[0] = ...
    input[1] = ...

    return input;
}
```

Next, your `addNumbers` and `multipleNumbers` method have a **return type**, why? You don't use it, then you don't need it. If you want to use it you should not throw the result away like

```
double resultAdd = addNumbers(x, y);
double resultMult = multiplyNumbers(x, y);

System.out.println("Result of x + y = " + resultAdd);
System.out.println("Result of x * y = " + resultMult);
```

---

> Can someone explain why my software intelliJ also says to use `static` in all the name of the methods?

Your program execution starts in the `main` method, a `static` method. At that point no objects are created. `static` means something is **not bound** to a specific object instance. If you want to be able to call non-static methods you would first need to create object instances. Imagine a class like

```
public class Human() {
    public void drink() { ... }
    public void eat() { ... }
}
```

If you want to be able to call `drink` or `eat` you first need to create some `Human` instance like

```
Human john = new Human();
Human abigail = new Human();

john.eat();
abigail.drink();
```

The methods are specific to the instance. So `john` may still be thirsty since we called `drink` only on `abigail`. A `static` method is not specific to an instance. If we add the following method

```
public class Human {
    public static void getIQ() { ... }
}
```

It may only be able to return the average IQ of a human, not the IQ of `john`. The method does not know anything about instances like `john` and we could call it even if we didn't yet create instances like `john`. That is also why we should indicate calling of a `static` method like

```
Human.getIQ();
```

and not as

```
john.getIQ();
```

Unfortunately, the second variant is possible and does compile. But it confuses since the call is not executed *on* `john`.

In your code example, since you didn't created any instances of classes, you need `static` methods to call them.

Comment: `You can only assign one variable at a time.` This is incorrect. `int a = 3; int b = a = 4;` is completely valid, and will set both `a` and `b` to 4.

Answer (score 0):

In main method you are calling some methods and passing x and y, You have not declared what x and why means.

You should declare the variables first then use them other wise for compiler 'x' and 'y' doesn't mean anything until you declare their type.

In programming we declare variable and assign default values to them e.g

```
double x = 0.0;
double y = 0.0;
```

In your code just assign default values as mentioned above, then scanner input would then be assigned to them afterwards.

Hope you got it.

Comment: if x and y are 0 the setNumbers method changes then but these values dont get passed onto the addition method or multiplication method and gives output of 0 which is wrong. this was my problem.

Comment: buti think someone has answered my question now.